# From *gint to gdouble gtk

Tags: c, gtk, glade

How can I set value to `gint*` variable instead `gdouble`?

```
gint *s;

gtk_tree_model_get( model, & data->iter, 0, &s, -1);

gtk_spin_button_set_value (GtkSpinButton *spin_button,
                           gdouble value);
```

Something like that:

```
gtk_spin_button_set_value (GtkSpinButton *spin_button,
                           s);
```

It is possible?

Comment: Please show your actual problem. As given, your question is not clear. See [ask]. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: So, I have some values of record in gint * variables and I need to present they in spin button while I am editing record. I have to set spin value but I can't because I don't know how to convert gint * to gdouble.

Comment: `gint *` is a _pointer_. How do you think a _pointer_ converted to _double_ wil make any sense?? And follow the links I provided.

Comment: What type would be `* gint`? Please get the syntax right. Do you possibly mean a `gint`?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my post. Can you check it now?

Comment: It is as badly as I thought. You really want to cast a pointer to `double`.

Answer (score -1):

An explicit solution would be to do the following:

```
gdouble value = (gdouble)(*your_gint_pointer);
gtk_spin_button_set_value(your_spin_button_pointer, value);
```

Floating points handle integer values without a loss of precision, so that's safe.

Comment: "Floating points handle integer values without a loss of precision" is plain wrong! Please check the **guaranteed** mantissa bits of a `double`. Note that and `int` can have more than 32 bits.

Comment: And why do you need `value` anyway? Even a cast is not required and should not be used (presuming the ranges do match).